# No Log File Created

Tags: python, logging

I've been learning about logging, and got help here earlier on setting up a logger w/external config file.

I've setup based on the example, however the messages only seen on the console and not in a long file (not created.

Can you please see what I'm doing wrong?

utilityLogger:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''
My app
'''
# ~~~~~ LOGGING SETUP ~~~~~ #
# set up the first logger for the app
import os
import testLogging as vlog
# path to the current script's dir
scriptdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

LOG_CONFIG = '../config/logging.conf'
print scriptdir

def logpath():
     '''
    Return the path to the main log file; needed by the logging.yml
    use this for dynamic output log file paths & names
    '''
    global scriptdir
    return (vlog.logpath(scriptdir = scriptdir, logfile = 'log.txt'))

logger = vlog.log_setup(config_file=LOG_CONFIG, logger_name="app")
logger.debug("App is starting...")
```

testLogging:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Functions to set up the app logger
'''
import logging
import logging.config
import os

LOG_CONFIG = '../config/logging.conf'

def logpath(scriptdir, logfile):
    '''
    Return the path to the main log file; needed by the logging.yml
    use this for dynamic output log file paths & names
    '''
   log_file = os.path.join(scriptdir, logfile)
   print log_file
   print scriptdir
   print logfile
   return(logging.FileHandler(log_file))

def log_setup(config_file, logger_name):
    '''
    Set up the logger for the script
    config = path to YAML config file
    '''
# Config file relative to this file
    logging.config.fileConfig(config_file)
    return(logging.getLogger(logger_name))
```

logging.conf file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=app

[logger_app]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=app
propagate=true

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('%(logfilename)s',)

[main]
()=__main__.logpath
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s (%(name)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d:%(levelname)s) %
(message)s # %(module)s:
datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s (%(name)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d:%(levelname)s) %(message)s # %(module)s:
datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Update, the question has already been marked as answered and I appreciate @zwer help!

Last objective, to understand, is there more pythonic way to instantiate a logger to Class (but I want to be able to log in main as well). With the marked answer I've put together the following, but I'm not sure it's the most elegant solution for both main and classes logging.

```
class TestLog(object):
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger
        self.__sub_test = 0

    def add_test(self):
        self.logger.debug('addition')
        a = 1 + 1
        self.logger.debug('result {}'.format(a, 1))

   def sub_test(self):
       self.logger.debug('subtraction')
       b = 5 -2
       self.logger.debug('result {}'.format(b, 1))

def main():
    logger = vlog.log_setup(config_file=LOG_CONFIG, logger_name="app", 
    log_file=LOG_PATH)
    logger.debug("App is starting...")
    test1 = TestLog(logger)
    print test1.add_test()
    print test1.sub_test()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: The handlers are set to consoleHandler in your config file which writes to `sys.stdout`. Change to fileHandler.

Comment: @Dan I'm not sure I follow your comment, since my fileHandler takes an arg for file name to output to.

Comment: Your `[handlers]` `keys` entry contains only `consoleHandler` - your fileHandler never gets initialized.

Comment: @zwer thank you, but switching to `keys=fileHandler,` I get ` Bad value substitution key    : logfilename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, let's pack it as an answer to avoid comment constraints.

The main issue with your config is that you're not initializing your fileHandler at all. If you want to use it, make sure you add it to the `[handlers]` section, e.g.:

```
[handlers]
keys=fileHandler
```

As for your other error, since in your `[handler_fileHandler]` you define a dynamic argument `logfilename` for the name of the file so you need to provide it when you're loading your logging config in Python, e.g.:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(config_file, defaults={"logfilename": "your_log_filename.log"})
```

That should do the trick.

**UPDATE** - As long as you provide a proper file path, the stated should work, but you still need to modify your config a little bit more to enable the file logger in all your loggers. So change your config to:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter,fileFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler
qualname=app

[logger_app]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler
qualname=app
propagate=true

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('%(logfilename)s',)

[main]
()=__main__.logpath
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s (%(name)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d:%(levelname)s) %(message)s # %(module)s:
datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s (%(name)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d:%(levelname)s) %(message)s # %(module)s:
datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Also, to make it more flexible, change your `testLogging.log_setup()` to something like:

```
def log_setup(config_file, logger_name, log_file):
    # Config file relative to this file
    logging.config.fileConfig(config_file, defaults={"logfilename": log_file})
    return logging.getLogger(logger_name)
```

And finally, when you're setting it up just invoke it as:

```
LOG_CONFIG = '../config/logging.conf'
LOG_PATH = r"C:\PycharmProjects\scrap\test.log"  # make sure it exists and is accessible!

logger = vlog.log_setup(config_file=LOG_CONFIG, logger_name="app", log_file=LOG_PATH)
logger.debug("App is starting...")
```

Adjusted for your local paths it should work as expected. I just tested it on my side and it's giving a proper result.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. When I the second part of your solution I get the following: updated line `logging.config.fileConfig(config_file, defaults={"logfilename": "C:\\PycharmProjects\\scrap\\test.log"})` Error: `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('a') or filename:` I tried with `/`, `\\\`, and abs path, but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: @Simply_me - try defining it as: `defaults={"logfilename": r"C:\PycharmProjects\scrap\test.log"}` and make sure that folder exists (the `logging` module will not create the path).

Comment: thank you very much for updating and detailing the changes and why. I've marked this as the answer but updated the question w/a last section if you care to review.

Comment: interestingly enough, I need to put `r` and double slashes for the solution to work or single forward slash.

Comment: @Simply_me - that's weird, it should work with _raw_ strings and single slashes just fine, that's the whole point of the `r` marker. Forward slashes will work without escape shenanigans, too. As for your update, if you want to define your loggers outside of your class that's probably the best way to do it, otherwise, to inherit root's logger setup, instead of passing a _reference_ you can just grab a logger when you instantiate it (something like: `self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)`) to have its logging entries correctly identified as comming from your class.